# Can't save chosen item from spinner to database

Tags: android, sql, database, spinner

I have problem with my database. I want to save selected item from spinner to `sql` database. The problem is,i don't know why, but i can't save chosen item from spinner to database. I was trying out this database with `EditText` and everything was fine.

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
DatabaseHelper db;
Spinner spinner;
Button addData, showData;
TextView saveChosenItemFromSpinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    addData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addDataBtn);
    showData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showDataBtn);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinnerDemo, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    saveChosenItemFromSpinner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    AddData();
//        showData();
}




@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String text = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    saveChosenItemFromSpinner.setText(text);
//        Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    AddData();
}

public void AddData() {
    addData.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isInserted = db.insertData(saveChosenItemFromSpinner.getText().toString() );
                    if (isInserted)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
}
```

DatabaseHelper class :

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TrainingPlan.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Chest";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "Upper_section";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,UpperSectionExercises TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String upperSectionExercisesString) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, upperSectionExercisesString);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}
}
```

I've tried to find solution on my own,but i find nothing. Can i have some tips?

Comment: The function `AddData()` is actually setting up the click listener. I think your logic itself will not work. Because, when the user selects an item, the `onItemSelected` function is called, which fetches the selected data in `text` variable. Then it calls `AddData()` function. Which is actually setting a click listener to the button`addData`. Instead, you should set the listener in the `onCreate` method after the variable declaration. And, inside `AddData()` function. simply call the function `db.insertData` with the text.

Comment: does saveChosenItemFromSpinner  changes as different text is selected from spinner?

Answer (score 0):

You are using different key with content values than your column name.

use

```
contentValues.put("UpperSectionExercises", upperSectionExercisesString);
```

or change your create statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your Table creation query is wrong. It will be like

```
      db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY 
      KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+ COL_2+" TEXT)");
```